# Callbacks from Sonos not being received on production

Tags: laravel, sonos, laravel-forge

My website does not seem to be handling callbacks from a Sonos webhook on production.

In my `routes/web` file i defined:

`Route::post('/sonos/callback', 'SonosCallbackController@callback');`

My `callback` function:

```
public function callback(Request $request)
    {
        Log::debug('REQ:');
        Log::debug($request);
    }
```

Posting from Postman works (when using the EXACT same headers and payload Sonos sends), my logs are filled.

When i change the callback URL in Sonos to a https://webhook.site page, i see the requests being triggered from Sonos. But when i change the callback URL to my production URL, it does not seem to work.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Did you check your apache/nginx access and error logs? Maybe the request does come in but the logging does not write as expected

Comment: There are no callbacks to find in my nginx access logs, apart from the ones sent from Postman.

Comment: how did you exclude that path from the csrf token check?

Comment: @lagbox `protected $except = ['sonos/callback'];` in the `VerifyCsrfToken` class.